# Creating ui-select with delete button in the same line

Tags: css, angularjs, styles

I'm trying to add a delete button to a ui-select field, the button works fine but it is located in a new line, any idea what to do.

### Field Image

[image: Field Image]

This is what I'm aiming for

[image]

Thanks

Comment: check out this link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#button-addons.Atleast google before posting @Yaniv Agam'

Comment: i'm not sure how to make it work with ui-select

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview Check this